# How to display concatenate value from query in datagridview C#

Tags: c#

I want to show data in datagridview from mysql, here is my query :

```
SELECT Max(t.trans_id)                                           'No', 
       Concat('A-', RIGHT(Concat('0000000', t.trans_mbr_id), 8)) 'Id Member', 
       m.mbr_nama                                                'Nama', 
       t.trans_toko_id                                           'Id Toko', 
       k.toko_nama                                               'Nama Toko' 
FROM   transaksi t 
       JOIN member m 
         ON( t.trans_mbr_id = m.mbr_id ) 
       JOIN toko k 
         ON( t.trans_toko_id = k.toko_id ) 
WHERE  t.trans_mbr_id IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY t.trans_id ASC
```

the problem is, **Id Member** column only displayed a box with a **red "x" sign** then an **exception** `system.argumentException invalid parameter`, when I try to close the exception box, it keeps appearing over and over again until i stop debugging.

thank you

Comment: Can you post your `DataGridView` html?

Comment: my project is desktop app, sorry didn't mention it before